# unit test to assert that Objects in a TreeMap are in the correct order?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, classcastexception, treemap

I am trying to write a `Junit` test to assert that Objects in my `TreeMap` are in the *correct order*.

How can I do so?

I am trying to do the following:

```
assertEquals(treeMapFromMethod.get(0), ValueThatShouldBeFirstEntryInTreeMap);
```

But I am getting the **error**:

```
"java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to MyObJect"
```

This error relates to the Line above.

How can I fix this/ is there a better way to test this?

Comment: Is the TreeMap typed as TreeMap<MyObject, XYZ>? It seems to me as if Java cannot cast 0 to MyObject.

Comment: You'll need to iterate the map (values), there's no index based `get()`.

Comment: ok thanks Ill try iterating the values

Comment: You can as well  get the list of keys from the tree map and compare it with expected list.

Comment: Your ClassCastException is probably caused by misuse of generics.  Enable all compiler warnings, remove any `@SuppressWarnings` annotations, and address all the warnings.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Hamcrest you can do this easily with the `contains` matcher:

```
TreeMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put("one", 1);
map.put("two", 2);
map.put("three", 3);

Assert.assertThat(map.keySet(), Matchers.contains("one", "three", "two"));
```

The `contains` matcher checks, if the given collection has the same length and contains the given items in the same order.